# Finding mean using linearity

Tags: probability, statistics

If I have that $E(X) = 2$, and am trying to find $E[3(X-1)]$, then is my process correct?

$$E[3(X-1)] = E(3X-3) = E(3X) - 3 = 3E(X) - 3 = 3(2) - 3 = 6-3 = 3$$

Thanks

Edit: E(X) = 2 not 3

Comment: Why 3(2)-3, and not 3*3-3?

Comment: sorry mean is 2, my bad

Comment: I think it’s correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your given procedure is correct. Usually, one writes $3 \cdot 2$ or $3 * 2$ instead of $3(2)$.